# What is the best way to do Error Handling in React Native App.

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, error-handling

There are a few approaches which people use.

**1**: One way is to use **hoc's(Higher Order components)** with global handlers using **interceptors** in axios.

**2**: Another way is to create an action creator for error and store errors in **Reducer store**, Fire the one action creator which is responsible for catching errors from the catch block. Currently, in most places, we have unhandled promise rejection.

Please let me know if there is any other approach to error handling, we want to show different error messages to the user for different errors. Example: Error can occur while accepting the order.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [error boundary](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html). Wrap your root app inside ErrorBoundary, then you'll be able to catch error in any of the components:

```
<ErrorBoundary>
  <App />
</ErrorBoundary>
```

Here's a demo from the docs: [Catching errors with error boundary](https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/wqvxGa?editors=0010)

Comment: This will only cover non-native errors and crashes inside the React Native JS bundle.